# tooltips don't work bootstrap 5 wordpress-gulp-starter-kit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack, gulp, bootstrap-5

I don't understand why, but tooltips don't work for me.

My work is based on this repository https://github.com/oguilleux/webpack-gulp-wordpress-starter-theme

Please write back if you need more information.

my main.js file

```js
import PopperJs from "./_popper";
import BootstrapPlugins from "./_bootstrapplugins";
import TinySlider from './_tinySlider';


const App = {
    /**
     * App.init
     */
    init() {
        //scripts init
        function initTinySlider() {
            return new TinySlider();
        }
        function initPopperJs() {
            return new PopperJs();
        }
        function initBootstrapPlugins(){
            return new BootstrapPlugins();
        }
        initTinySlider();
        initPopperJs();
        initBootstrapPlugins();
    }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    App.init();
});
```

my bootstrapplugins.js file

```js
import {Dropdown , Tooltip} from "bootstrap";

class BootstrapPlugins {
    constructor() {
        this.dropdownInit();
        this.tooltipInit();
    }
    dropdownInit() {
        return Dropdown ;
    }
    tooltipInit(){
        return Tooltip ;
    }
}

export default BootstrapPlugins;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere) this is the way to initialize Tooltips :

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

If I were to implement it in the WP theme with ES6 it would give something like this in your bootstrapplugins.js :

```
import {Dropdown , Tooltip} from "bootstrap";

class BootstrapPlugins {
    constructor() {
        this.dropdownInit();
        this.tooltipInit();
    }
    dropdownInit() {
        return Dropdown ;
    }
    tooltipInit(){
        const tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
        tooltipTriggerList.map((tooltipTriggerEl) => new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl));
    }
}

export default BootstrapPlugins;
```

Comment: thank you very match! By the way, Olivier you did great wp-bootstrap repository!